# TexStudio, How to Insert Graphics with Automatic Suffix

Tags: texstudio, eps

When you use TexStudio (iOS), you can drag and drop a figure from finder to the code of TexStudio, then a window of "Insert Graphics" prop out and let you put in the figure with convenience.

However, this function will not include the suffix of my file. e.g. if I add "123.eps", it becomes "123" in LaTex. How can I keep the ".eps"? rather than adding them one by one manually.

It becomes a problem as eps files will fail to be compiled if ".eps" is ignored, and we don't have this problem for pdf etc.

Best regards,

Comment: Hi David, for my case it seems my class included something that will convert eps file into pdf, but it requires a suffix of ".eps" to work properly. So would you please recommend any method to include eps directly into LaTex output?  Best, Zhonglu

Comment: sorry can't help with that: that's purely a question about how the drag and drop is configured and I don't have  texstudio or ios:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping the extension is not possible. This is hard-coded.

You'll have to manually add the extension back in if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this in preamble, and then there is no need to add Suffix

```
 \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg,.eps}
```